# Upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 broke pip for python3.6

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

After upgrading from 18.04 to 19.04, I can't use pip on virtualenvs with python3.6.

```
$ pip install scipy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 14, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
  File "/home/xen0f0n/dibco_local/dibco_python/lib/python3.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from distutils import dist, sysconfig
ImportError: cannot import name 'dist'
```

When tried to re-create virtual env

```
$ virtualenv my_python -p /usr/bin/python3.6

Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
    import distutils.sysconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apport'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 25, in <module>
    import distutils.sysconfig
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
```

I think the problem is with python3-distutils.
Anyone out there facing the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried re-creating the virtual environment?

Comment: Yeah, throws exceptions... 


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.sysconfig'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apport'